# Can Termux adb push file from unrooted phone to tablet via OTG cable?

Tags: adb, 5.1-lollipop, usb-on-the-go, termux

Can I use Termux to send an app (APK file) via, e.g., adb push, from my unrooted Samsung Galaxy S10 phone to an unrooted Android 5.1.1 tablet via an OTG cable?

Comment: ok got it. your goal is *'adb backup -apk <pkgname>'* on host, then adb push, switch host <-> client and *'adb restore backup.ab'* all from within termux (ignoring apk is most likely not compatible between android versions), or unpacking backup.ab to get apk only

Comment: unfortunately *'adb start-server'* requires root (at least for usb connection). once the connection is established it works without root permissions. is adb over wifi an option for you? https://github.com/MasterDevX/Termux-ADB

Comment: there is an app claiming to do this without root (did not work for me) https://github.com/KhunHtetzNaing/ADB-OTG

Comment: @alecxs wireless ADB should work.

Comment: @IrfanLatif question is about OTG cable. i believe the API used in that apps is sufficient. only authorization is unclear to me. any idea on non-rooted device? after *'su -c ../usr/bin/adb -d start-server'* in termux authorization dialog appears. once established adb works without root

Comment: @alecxs yes but we need to go for alternative when there are technical limitations. On Android `/dev/` is never going to be fully accessible (in DAC and MAC) to user apps anytime in future. If we see a library with USB host APIs for ADB commands, that would be awesome. But doesn't seem very probable. For `fastboot` there's already one available from Google.